# Relationship of the Derivative of the Gaussian to the Second Order Moment (PRML Exercise 1.8)

Tags: machine-learning, probability, normal-distribution

In exercise 1.8 of Bishop's PRML, he asks to differentiate both sides of the normalization condition of the Gaussian as given by:

$$
\int^{\infty}_{-\infty} \mathcal{N}(x|\mu, \sigma^2) dx = 1
$$

with respect to $\sigma^2$ in order to demonstrate that the Gaussian satisfies the condition:

$$
\mathbb{E}[x^2] = \int^{\infty}_{-\infty} \mathcal{N}(x|\mu, \sigma^2) x^2 dx = \mu^2 + \sigma^2
$$

Although I can do the calculation, I am failing to see the motivation for the question (and it seems that the authors almost always has a well planned reason for each exercise).

Conceptually, what does the derivative of the Gaussian with respect to $\sigma^2$ have to do with the second order moment of the Gaussian?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears to be just an alternative and faster way to show that the parameter $\sigma^2$ is the variance of the distribution. The straight one (see [for example here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/519631/87400)) is rather tiresome. Just to provide some (condensed) content here we have

$$\frac {\partial}{\partial \sigma^2}\int^{\infty}_{-\infty} \mathcal{N}(x|\mu, \sigma^2) dx = \frac {\partial}{\partial \sigma^2}1=0$$

$$\implies \frac {1}{2\sigma^2}\int^{\infty}_{-\infty} \mathcal{N}(x|\mu, \sigma^2)\cdot \left[-1+\frac {(x-\mu)^2}{\sigma^2}\right] dx = 0$$

$$\implies -\frac {1}{2\sigma^2}+\frac {1}{2\sigma^4}E(X-\mu)^2=0$$

$$\sigma^2=E(X-\mu)^2 $$

The same method can be used to show that $\mu = E(X)$.